# when i hit try to mirror bones, my bones decided to deform to have one size smaller than the other...why?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature, bones

[image]
[image]

when i hit shift e to add a mirrored armature onto a single point it does this deformed thing (i dont know how else to describe it) that you see in the image attached, and i dont know how to fix it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, what is Shift E supposed to do? To mirror an armature you need to select the bones and Armature > Symmetrize

Comment: symmetrize just made it worse

Comment: https://youtu.be/mXNK0A8W56Y maybe this will better explain my problem

Comment: Could you please share your file? Share the armature only, read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know the Shift E, I've just tested and it works fine in Blender 3 and 4 so there must be something wrong with your armature or the way you do it. Also another way to build your armature is to only build the left or right part, name the bones with the _L or _R suffixe, and symmetrize afterwards.

Comment: Your armature origin isn't centered.  Consider applying location first (looks like it's supposed to be originated on world origin.)   It's mirroring about the armature plane, not the world plane.

Comment: (https://blend-exchange.com/b/V75VpgK7/) i added the blend file...im not sure how to add the armature only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nathan says, the X mirror takes the origin position as center of the symmetry, as it's offset your extrusion is messed up:

[image]

You need to bring back the origin at the center of the armature in *Object* mode with a <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*. Once done the extrusion works as you expect it to do:

[image]